# Scrapy: spider returns nothing

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, web-crawler, scrapy

this is my first time creating a spider and in spite my efforts it continues to return nothing to my csv export. My code is:

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import Selector

class Emag(CrawlSpider):
    name = "emag"
    allowed_domains = ["emag.ro"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.emag.ro/"]

    rules = (Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=(r'www.emag.ro')), callback="parse", follow= True))

    def parse(self, response):
        sel = Selector(response)
        sites = sel.xpath('//a/@href').extract()
        for site in sites:
            site = str(site)

        for clean_site in site:
            name = clean_site.xpath('//[@id=""]/span').extract()
            return name
```

the thing is that if i print the sites, it bring me a list of the URLs, which is OK. if i search for the name inside one of the URLs in scrapy shell, it will find it. the problem is when i what all the names in all links crawled.I run it with "scrapy crawl emag>emag.csv"

Can you please give me a hint whats wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Multiple problems in the spider:

- `rules` should be an iterable, missing comma before the last parenthesis
- no `Item`s specified - you need to define an [`Item`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/items.html) class and return/yield it from the spider `parse()` callback

Here's a fixed version of the spider:

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.item import Field, Item


class MyItem(Item):
    name = Field()


class Emag(CrawlSpider):
    name = "emag"
    allowed_domains = ["emag.ro"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.emag.ro/"]

    rules = (Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=(r'www.emag.ro')), callback="parse", follow=True), )

    def parse(self, response):
        sel = Selector(response)
        sites = sel.xpath('//a/@href')
        for site in sites:
            item = MyItem()
            item['name'] = site.xpath('//[@id=""]/span').extract()
            yield item
```

Comment: thks a lot for taking the time. yet it still extracts nothing; its smth wrong with the xpath selection also?

Comment: @user3753592 try running spider this way: `scrapy crawl -o output.csv -t csv`.

Comment: thks, that was the initial way i run them. nevertheless either way i still got empty files

Comment: @user3753592 what do you really want to extract from the web site pages? I don't understand the intention of the xpath you've provided. I thought you've omitted `id` intentionally.

Comment: no, i want to extract the name of the products and the price

Comment: not sure how to incorporate [@id="products-holder"] in order to capture all the IDs no matter what it holds

Answer (score 0):

One problem might be, you have been forbidden by robots.txt for the site
You can check that from the log trace.
If so go to your settings.py and make ROBOTSTXT_OBEY=False
That solved my issue